# How to set up an workflow in SharePoint to only work when a specific field is changed and not everytime the item is edited?

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

The issue is that everytime an item is edited/changed all the users who are set up to receive updates are notified. I need the workflow to run only when a specific field is changed disregarding the others. For example if my item contains these values (Customer Name; Acc#; Contact Person; Address;) - I need the workflow to work only when the Acc# is changed and only if it is changed, no metter how many times the other fields are changed.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick way to do it is to have the workflow store the value each time the it starts, then tell it to wait until the field != the stored value.  This may not work in all cases, but it could be enough for your purposes.

Comment: This sounds as a simpler solution, but how do I set up this workflow?

Comment: You'll need to use Sharepoint designer.  First create an action "set workflow variable" and set it to the value of the field.  Then use the action "wait for field change in current item," and tell it to wait for the field to not equal the variable.  Be sure that the workflow is triggered when the item is both created and changed.

Here's a tutorial that you could easily adapt: http://bytelab.blogspot.com/2008/01/custom-workflow-using-sharepoint.html

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You should create an [event handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms437502.aspx) to run on your content type or library. You can then check the before and after properties of the fields you mention. Then use the event handler to initiate the workflow if required.

Comment: Thanks Nat,
I am new to all this and novice in programing. I will try to get someone to help me with this, but it looks like this is what I need.